# is there any specific timeout value during asynchronous request to server when using xmlHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript

I was trying to define a timeout of 1 hour for a `xmlHttpRequest` with below code, but alert could not generate . Is there any specific limit of timeout beyond which we can not set the timeout for an asynchronous request with `xmHttprequest` object.

Please suggest if i want to set timeout for long time as my server goes to reboot due to which i have to wait for that much long time. And is there any other alternative in which i can define longer timeout.

Below code is working fine in IE8 if i set timeout to 12000 milliseconds. But  did not work when timeout is 1 hour.

```
var reqObject = null;

if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
    // Except old version IE
    reqObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if ( window.ActiveXObject ) {
    // For old version IE
    try {
        reqObject = new ActiveXObject( "Msxml2.XMLHTTP" );
    } catch ( e ) {
        try {
            reqObject = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
        } catch ( e ) {
            // cannot get object.
        }
    }
}

reqObject.open( "POST", url, true );
reqObject.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" );

reqObject.onreadystatechange = function() {
    try {
        if ( reqObject.readyState == 4 ) {
            if ( reqObject.status == 200 ) {
                // successful
                func( reqObject.responseText );
            } else {
                // error
                errfunc( reqObject.statusText );
            }
        }
    } catch ( e ) {
        // On some browsers, you may encounter the following exception.
        //  -->NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE
        // I saw it on Firefox(ver 3.6).
        // For more information, print 'e.message'.
        var errMsg;

        if ( e.name == JSERR_NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE ) {
            errMsg = "Cannot Connect";
        } else {
            errMsg = "Cannot Connect.";
        }

        // error
        errfunc( errMsg );
    }
}

reqObject.timeout = 3600000;
reqObject.ontimeout = function () {
    alert("Update process has Timed out.\nPlease check whether management node is up or not!!!");
}
reqObject.send( param );
```

Comment: What does happen when you try to set it to 1 hour? How exactly does it not work?

Comment: There was no alert generated for the same. Nothing happened, the page of GUI was stuck.

Comment: You mean you waited an hour but simply nothing happened? What do you mean by "stuck", that the UI froze for 1 hour?

Comment: Yes, nothing happened just after 1 hour and UI froze for more than one hour. I read that "If you set an XMLHttpRequest time-out value that is larger than the network stack's time-out value, the network stack will time out first and the ontimeout event will not be raised." at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304105(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user2916737 The `timeout` event only fires is the connection is *still alive* and *unresolved*. A long, inactive connection might die naturally (because the server terminates it). In that case, you'd get an `error` event when the connection dies and would not get a `timeout` event (because `timeout` is for still-alive connections).

Comment: apsillers: Thank you for response, I understand. In that case for long inactive connection, there is no way to show the error if server does not comes up after reboot?

Comment: @user2916737 When you server reboots, all the connections to it will be terminated; you can detect this with `onerror`. If you try to make a connection to a server when it's not online, the connection will die immediately. You can repeatedly try to make *new* connections, but the old connections (and failed connection attempts) are gone forever. Another way to put it: `timeout` only works if the server is up at connection time and stays up for the entirety of the connection. `Timeout` is mostly used to detect *very* slow networks and slow-responding servers.